# Como eliminar los elementos pares de una lista

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista

La tarea me pide descomponer en factores primos un numero y luego sumar los factores pares, hice esto pero me sale el error de que espera un `int` y recibe una lista:

```
return primos,[x for x in otralista if x % 2 == 0]
```

---

```
def descomponer(num):

    if num < 0:
        print("Su numero se convertira en positivo")
    ponum = abs(num)

    primos = []

    for i in range(2, ponum+1):
        while (ponum%i) == 0:
            primos.append(i)
            ponum = ponum/i
    return primos



num = int(input("ingrese un numero"))
print(f"los numeros primos que nos dan {num} son: \n {descomponer(num)}")
```

Comment: ¿Qué es otralista? Tu filtro es correcto, te faltaría sumar `sum(x for x in primos if x % 2 == 0)`, aunque dado que el único factor par es el 2, simplemente habría que ver si el factor es 2 o no. ¿El error de dónde sale por cierto? El código que muestras, aparte de lo de "otralista" no genera ninguna excepción ¿algún test?

Comment: fue un momento de estrés jaja, en mi mente con eso agregaría los elementos de primos a la nueva lista la cual llame "otralista" y ahí almacenar los pares, estaba muuy estresado por que se supone es un problema fácil y no me tome el tiempo de pensar bien como resolverlo

Answer (score 0):

Solo tenia que hacer la validacion de pares despues de hacer la validacion de primos.

Dejo el codigo por si a alguien le sirve:

```
def descomponer(num):
    if num < 0:
        print("Su numero se convertira en positivo")
    ponum = abs(num)
    primos = []
    otralista = []
    laSuma=0
    for i in range(2, ponum+1):
        while (ponum%i) == 0:
            primos.append(i)
            if i%2==0:
                otralista.append(i)
            ponum = ponum / i
    for k in otralista:
            laSuma = laSuma+k
    return primos, otralista, laSuma
num = int(input("ingrese un numero"))
print(f"los numeros primos que nos dan {num} son: \n {descomponer(num)}")
```